# Angular AG Grid Row Buffer is not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid

We are using AG Grid with Angular 5 having 100 columns and 5000 rows on IE browser, with row buffer 5000, when we scroll vertically the data flickers and takes more time to load i.e. 15-20 secs.

With row buffer set 9999 it takes more than 30 minutes to load grid and freezes IE and can not perform an action.

Can you please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: With Row Buffer set to 500  the grid loading is taking more than 15 minutes.

Comment: With out Row Buffer it loads fast but when we scroll vertically the data loading is taking more than 20 secs.

Comment: how about setting a low rowBuffer? If I understand the rowBuffer correctly, it is suppose to work in a way that you show up to lets say 50 rows, and then more and more rows will render when you scroll down

Answer (score -1):

`rowBuffer:500` will work. The same thing was required in my case.